# SectionHeader parallel to items in SectionList

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I am new to react-native and trying to create a UI which looks like this.

[Link to UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzSsm.jpg)

But I have no idea how to go about it, tried to use SectionList with renderSectionHeader but could not get the header parallel to the Item.

Comment: As far as I know, the renderSectionHeader prop for SectionList is not meant to be used in parallel in that way, only as a header above each section. My suggestion would be to go ahead and use a FlatList and instead create a `renderItem` component that can render both the circle date and the info card on every row, but add some logic to only render the first circle date for each day (or whatever time frame). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, Thats good suggestion, I'll try that but the trick would be to keep the date circle sticky. I was hoping for a simpler solution.